# Reading file input as opcode in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for a class at school. It is a simple implementation of stacks and queues. However as part of the project we are require to read opcode in from a file. The opcode is formated as follows:

```
append 10
serve
append 20
append 30
serve
push 10
push 50
push 20
push 20
pop
```

My problem is when I read in the file through a standard fstream it seems to pick up some kind of weird formatting or something, and won't match comparison checks.

I am wonder what I am doing wrong, how to fix it, and if there is a better way to manipulate opcode going forward. As it is, the if-else statement always goes to if. Kind of desperately need to get this working.

```
#include "StackAndQueue.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Stack leStack;
    Queue leQueue;

    //Read in the datafile. 
    cout << "Reading default file: p2datafile.txt";
        fstream data("p2datafile.txt");
        while (data.fail()){
                cout << " failed." << endl;
                data.close();
                cout << "Please enter path to datafile: ";
                string filename;
                cin >> filename;
                data.open(filename.c_str());
        }
        cout << endl << "Sucess!" << endl;

    //Loop through all the commands in the file
    while(!data.eof()){
        // Determine what kind of command is running 
        // and if parsing will be needed.

        string opcode;          
        getline(data,opcode,' ');

        if (opcode == "pop"){
            cout << "popping!" << endl;
            leStack.pop();
        }
        else if (opcode == "serve"){
            cout << "serving" << endl;
            leQueue.serve();
        }
        else if (opcode == "push"){
            cout << "pushing";
        }
        else{
            cout << "else!" << endl;
        }
    }
    data.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize if the code is difficult to read, and the general half-finished nature of it. I am still pretty new to this.

Comment: Could you please attach the wrong output you get? (BTW, get rid of that ugly system("pause");)

Comment: The standard stream operators automatically break on white space. But your getline() only breaks on space (not tab) so be careful the input file does not contain tabs (or use the operator>>).

Comment: Also your test of eof() is not correct. The eof flag is not set to true until you read past the end of file. So if you read the whole file (with nothing left) it will still be false and enter the loop. The next call to getline() will fail and leave opcodde in an indeterminate state (probably "" thus leading to printing "else!").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline` used in that way considers just `' '` as a delimiter, so it won't stop at newlines; moreover, you're not extracting the argument (when the opcodes has any), so it will get read as an opcode (sticked in front of the *real* opcode) at the next iteration.

In my opinion, you could simply get away with using just the normal `operator>>`. It stops correctly at any whitespace (which is what you want to do) and supports the C++ strings correctly. The important thing is to remember to extract also the argument when needed (again, with `operator>>`), watching for `istream::fail()` errors in case of bad number formatting. You may even want to have the stream rise exceptions in case of these errors (so they don't go unnoticed).

```
try
{
    string opcode;
    data.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    //Loop through all the commands in the file
    while(data>>opcode){
        // Determine what kind of command is running 
        // and if parsing will be needed.

        int argument;

        if (opcode == "pop"){
            cout << "popping!" << endl;
            leStack.pop();
        }
        else if (opcode == "serve"){
            cout << "serving" << endl;
            leQueue.serve();
        }
        else if (opcode == "push"){
            cout << "pushing";
            data >> argument;
        }
        else if (opcode == "append"){
            cout << "appending";
            data >> argument;
        }
        else{
            cout << "else!" << endl;
        }
    }
    data.close();
}
catch(const ios::failure & ex)
{
    if(!data.eof())
        cout<<"IO error"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This was really the answer! I don't know what getline was doing that was freaking it out so bad, but this works a whole lot better! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem; the problem with getline is that, calling it as you did, it stopped reading only on spaces, so, after the first line, it read the argument *and* the following opcode in the same string. *And*, as I wrote, you also didn't read the argument.

Answer (score 1):

the problem you are most likely having stems from the way you are reading input.  `std::getline(..., ' ')` extracts a string that ends with a space.  With the given input, the first string gotten will be `append`, but the second will be

```
10
serve
append
```

because there are no spaces.

How about this, instead of trying to read in an opcode exactly, read a line, and see if you can figure out if it *begins* with an opcode.

Comment: I was kind of aware this, but I wasn't get any kind of acknowledgement even when it read in serve with a simple if (getline(data, opcode, ' ') == serve) {cout << server is working;}

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reading the file a word a a time, read the entire line (using `std::getline`) then use a `std::stringstream` to process the line, something like this:

```
     std::string line;
     while(std::getline(file,line))
     {
        std::stringstream linestream(std::stringstream::in|std::stringstream::out);
        linestream << line;
        std::string command;
        if(std::getline(linestream,command,' '))
        {
        //process line - chain 'if(std::getline(linestream,command,' '))' to advance the token steam
        }
        else
            //error blank line
     }
```

Comment: Also fixed the bug with testing for eof `while(!data.eof())`

Comment: Easier to just declare linestream and initialize in one statement. `std::stringstream linestream(line);` The use operator >> to extract the command from the line (as it will read a white space separated word).

Comment: yeah, good points, this was quickly copy-pasted from an old project of mine so I never bothered with anything other then it being correct and compilable :)